# How to remove ( from the string

Tags: string, replaceall

I have a string value where I am getting the a integer with ')' I want to remove the ')' have the value separated from all the unwanted special characters. Do any one here have any idea how can I remove the ')'. I have tried `stringValue.replace('\)'. '')`, but it is not working.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Something like :

```
String s = '(09890)';
Integer i = Integer.valueOf(s.replaceAll('[\\(\\)]',''));
```